# What is difference between loopstate.Break(), loopState.Stop() and CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a simple question, i have following simple Parallel for loop. this for loop is part of windows service. I want to stop the loop, when someone stops the service. I can find three ways to stop parallel for, which is in if condition. What is the best way of stopping the parallel for loop and what are the differences?

```
       CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
       ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
       options.CancellationToken = cancellationToken.Token;

       Parallel.For(0, maximum_operations, options, (a, loopState) =>
        {
            {
                //Do something

                if(!KeepProcessing)
                { 
                    //loopState.Break();
                    //loopState.Stop();
                    cancellationToken.Cancel();

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CancellationToken` is used to **signal cancellation**.

`loopState.Break()` and `loopState.Stop()` are used to **end execution**.

Here's an example

```
Parallel.For(0, maximum_operations, options, (a, loopState) =>
    {
        // do work

        // cancellationToken.Cancel() should be called externally
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // cancellation requested - perform cleanup work if necessary

            // then call
            loopState.Break();
            // or
            loopState.Stop();
        }
    });
```

`loopState.Break()` means complete all iterations on all threads that are prior to the current iteration on the current thread, and then exit the loop ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx)).

`loopState.Stop()` means stop all iterations as soon as convenient ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx)).

---

Another way to terminate execution is call token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), but you will need to handle the `OperationCanceledException` exception:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
        Parallel.For(0, maximum_operations, options, (a, loopState) =>
        {
            // do work

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // handle cancellation
    }
}
```

All of these methods are valid ways to terminate execution of `Parallel.For`. Which one you use depends on your requirements.

For example:

- Is it essential to *immediately* stop all execution when your windows Service is stopped? Then you could use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`
- Does your loop deal with IDisposable objects that need cleanup? Then you could use `loopState.Break()` or `loopState.Stop()`

---

Some articles for reference:

- [MSDN: Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx)
- [MSDN: How to: Stop or Break from a Parallel.For Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx)