# Stop vs Break in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net, loops, task-parallel-library

I have difficulty to understand `loopState.Stop()` and `loopState.Break()`. I have read MSDN and several posts about it but I am still confused.

What I understand is that every iteration partitioner gives remaining indexes for threads to process and `loopState.Stop()` stops all threads and `loopState.Break()` stops the current thread.

However lets consider the following situation:

```
Parallel.For(0, 100, (i, loopState) =>
{
    if (i >= 10) 
        loopState.Break();
    Debug.Write(i);
});
```

For this loop I have following result:

```
0 25 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I have no idea why in the result there is 10 and 25 numbers.

Anyone can help?

P.S. I have i5 520M CPU (2 cores => 4 Threads)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`loopState.Break()` does not break the function like a `return`. So the line after the `loopState.Break()` will still be executed. After that scope has ended for that number, `for` checks if the `loopState.Break()` had been called. If so, all loops are allowed to continue until the number has been reached that called `Break`.

In your example, the loops with 0 till 24 will break at the same time as the loop 25 till 49 (and display their "breaking" numbers).

Loop 50..74 and 75..99 will not even get started because the second loop 25..49 has already aborted the whole for-operation, since their staring numbers are greater then the breaking number 10.

Comment: So loopState.Break() exits all threads? I use to thing that loopState.Stop() does it.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: I understand now how the first two loops stops but why the two other threads do not even starts? Is Break able to terminate more then one thread? If so how it does it?

Comment: See for a good answer about Stop vs Break: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818203/what-is-difference-between-loopstate-break-loopstate-stop-and-cancellationt

Comment: @MichałJankowski The other two don't start probably because they just don't get time to - if you put a Thread.Sleep(1) just before `loopState.Break()` they sometimes *do* start executing.

Comment: @svick+Michal: I adjusted my answer. I wanted my anwer as simple as possible. But this was too simple. Thanx for the update.

Comment: I finally got it :) - thank's a lot for short and clear answer.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest answer:

both stop and break prevent new iterations to be started. Both ensure that started iteration finish.

difference - stop - aborts the iteration it called in and break doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation of `Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx):

> Break may be used to communicate to the loop that no other iterations after the current iteration need be run. For example, if Break is called from the 100th iteration of a for loop iterating in parallel from 0 to 1000, all iterations less than 100 should still be run, but the iterations from 101 through to 1000 are not necessary.

What this means is that the current iteration will still finish (so `10` gets printed). `Break()` also isn't capable of time travel, so the `25` will stay printed. What `Break()` means is that no *new* iterations beyond `10` will be started.

Answer (score 4):

`if (i >= 10)  loopState.Break();` will still continue the current iteration. So `10` is printed.

However, iterations (i >= 10) after the `loopState.Break()` called will not start.

But why `25` is printed? The following image will explain why. Since you have 4 threads, 0-99 will be divided as 4.

1st thread has: 0-24. 
2nd thread has: 25 - 49. 
3rd thread has: 50 - 74. 
4th thread has: 75 - 99.

Based on my understanding, each thread will loop the numbers itself. According to [this post](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/ParallelClass.html), it says

> Additional iterations may be run, if they were already started when Break was called.

As the 2nd thread has started almost the same time as the 1st thread, so `0, 25` is printed. Then `if (i >= 10)  loopState.Break();` is called when looping `25` in the 2nd thread.

The loops in 3rd and 4th thread did not start before the `Break()` is called hence any number greater than `10` did not print.

[image]
image ref: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx

Answer (score 2):

All methods from static `Parallel` class returns `ParallelLoopResult`.This object has two properties - `IsCompleted` and `LowestBreakIteration`

When we use `loopState.Break()`, `LowestBreakIteration` returns an integer that represents the lowest iteration from which the Break statement was called

When we use `loopState.Stop()`, `LowestBreakIteration` Returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

**Break** ensures that all iterations that are currently running will be finished.

**Stop** just terminates everything.

Comment: That's not true. Stop() causes that no more new iteration will be executed. But all running iterations/threads are still allowed to finish. If you want to early exit within the Action then you need to test for state.IsStopped.
For an example see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop

Comment: This is not true indeed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop?#remarks

Answer (score 0):

```
void Log(string prefix, bool isBreak=false) 
{
    var msg = isBreak ? " Break" : "";
    Console.WriteLine($"{prefix} task: {Task.CurrentId.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0')} {msg}");

}
long lockFlag=0;
Parallel.For(0, 130, (i, loopState) =>
{
    if (i >= 10 && Interlocked.Read(ref lockFlag)==0)
    {
        lockFlag=Interlocked.Increment(ref lockFlag);
        loopState.Break();
        //Statement after break will still execute for current iteration
        Log(i.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0'),true);
    }
    else
    {
      Log(i.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0')); 
    }
});
```

[image]

Tasks "8904" keep running to complete all iterations less than 25. Obviously if iterations have already completed that represent values greater than 25, then
there will be no way of rolling back.

If you do want to terminate the loop as soon as possible and don’t care about guaranteeing that all prior iterations
have completed, then ParallelLoopState has another method called **Stop()**. The Stop method attempts to end the
loop as soon as possible—once issued, no loop task will start a new iteration