# Parallel.For Conditional Statement

Tags: c#, .net, parallel.for

I'm running a simulations in Parallel.For loops, but I need to stop then after a certain period of even if it hasn't run all the iterations.

I need to be able to do the following in Parallel.For.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000 || DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime) >= MaxDuration; i++)
{
    // do the thing
}
```

Comment: FYI:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-for(system-int32-system-int32-system-action((system-int32-system-threading-tasks-parallelloopstate))) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break?view=net-6.0

Comment: I've never used Parallel.For myself, but checking your condition manually in the loop body and [calling loopState.Break](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16261663/87698) should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Heinzi in the comment, calling [ParallelLoopState.Break()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate) works after checking the condition

```
Parallel.For(1, 1_000_000, (i, state) =>
{
    //do the thing

    if (DateTime.Now-startTime>=maxDuration)
    {   
        state.Break();
    }

});
```